# how to border around grid

Tags: wpf

i need to draw a border around  a grid and around every row of grid?

around a grid is simple. but inside every row i have another grid and all inside grid have multiple column and have button in all of columns. 
so i need to draw border around every column ,every grid and every button.

i tried to do by using multiple  about every row but error is coming that you cannot have ribbonbutton inside the border.

do i need to use multiple  around every column of every grid?

i tried but nothing is working. i am new in WPF.

Answer (score 3):

It is intended for debug purposes but may help you

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Ribbon buttons can be used outside of Ribbons.  That has nothing to do with your Border problem.  You may just have to use a regular Button.  There are many ways you can template it to improve the visual look.

Here's a simple example of putting borders around grids and cells:

```
<Window x:Class="TestingWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:TestingWPF.Properties"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="Test" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="4" Padding="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.RowSpan="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BorderBrush="#FF00FF51"/>

            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3">
                <Button />
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                <Button />
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3">
                <Button />
            </Border>

            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">
                <Button />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3">
                <Button />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

You could easily replicate that in code by creating your grid in a loop.  You might want to look into templating to achieve a better result but you'd have to be more specific about *what* you're trying to accomplish instead of *how* you are trying to accomplish something.